# Spring data r2dbc error - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using Spring data r2dbc and facing a strange issue.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
runtimeOnly 'dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql'
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

Getting error with update query.

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE appt SET notes = :newNotes WHERE appt_id = :apptId AND org_id = :orgId")
Mono<Integer> updateAppt(long apptId, int orgId, String newNotes);
```

**Error :-**

```
Caused by: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcNonTransientResourceException: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Test create Appointment - Updated'
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.ExceptionFactory.mappingSqlState(ExceptionFactory.java:115) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ SQL "UPDATE appt SET notes = :newNotes WHERE appt_id = :apptId AND org_id = :orgId" [DatabaseClient]
Stack trace:
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.ExceptionFactory.mappingSqlState(ExceptionFactory.java:115) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:102) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.TextQueryHandler.accept(QueryFlow.java:317) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.TextQueryHandler.accept(QueryFlow.java:292) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.util.DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.java:70) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
```

Query thru SQL bench works fine.

```
UPDATE appt SET notes = 'Test create Appointment - Updated' WHERE appt_id = 1 AND org_id = 2;
```

Comment: How does your entity look like?

Comment: I dont see any issue with the Entity. It works fine thru JPA entity but not with the query. Getting the same error for any update query. Looks like a bug in Spring data r2dbc.

Comment: R2DBC doesn't support JPA annotations, so the entity has to look very different.

Comment: Can you get the SQL string _after_ the values have been filled in?

Comment: We can print SQL. But there is no way get the SQL with the values.

Comment: Update thru JPA object works but not thru the query. But, select thru the query works.

Comment: Please, be aware of the second information tip in the Spring Data R2DBC documentation when they explain [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries): `R2DBC repositories internally bind parameters to placeholders with Statement.bind(…) by index.`. Please, try to define the method as `Mono<Integer> updateAppt(String newNotes, long apptId, int orgId);` - note the change in the order of params - with the provided query and see if it works. MySQL is clearly complaining about the use of `'Test create Appointment...'` as numeric.

Comment: This is correct. This is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: Do you mean that with the proposed change in the method signature everything works ok?

Comment: Yes, I found that this morning.

Comment: That is great @user1578872, I am happy to hear that. Do you mind if I post the answer with this solution? Is it fine for you?

Comment: sure, that should work

Comment: Thank you very much @user1578872. I am very sorry for not being able to help you before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, be aware of the second information tip in the Spring Data R2DBC documentation when they explain [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries):

> R2DBC repositories internally bind parameters to placeholders with `Statement.bind(…)` by index.

Please, try to define your method as:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE appt SET notes = :newNotes WHERE appt_id = :apptId AND org_id = :orgId")
Mono<Integer> updateAppt(String newNotes, long apptId, int orgId);
```

Please, note the change in the order of the parameters.

MySQL is clearly complaining about the use of the value `'Test create Appointment - Updated'` as numeric.